# $_FILES array is empty while uploading product image in Magento 1.7 admin

Tags: magento-1.7, product-images

I am getting error **$_FILES array is empty** while trying to upload an product image in magento 1.7 backend. 2 days ago I installed patches from 5344 to 8788.

[image]

How can I rid off this problem. please help.

Comment: Check your server log and exception file

Answer (score 0):

There may be numerous reasons behind $_FILES array is empty while uploading product image-

- Check php.ini for file_uploads- On, post_max_size, upload_max_size.
- Priviliges to your media folder
- Enough space either in PHP tmp catalog or media catalog
- Make sure your  tag has the enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute. No other tag will work, it has to be your FORM tag. Double
  check that it is spelled correctly. Double check that
  multipart/form-data is surrounded by straigh quotes, not smart
  quotes.
- Make sure your FORM tag has method="POST". GET requests do not
  support multipart/form-data uploads.
- Make sure your file input tag has a NAME attribute. An ID attribute
  is noy sufficient! ID attributes are for use in the DOM, not for POST
  payloads.
- Make sure that the file you are uploading does not have any
  non-alphanumeric characters in it.

Cross check all of them and your issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I found Only one solution for resloving the issue

Go on php.ini file and just update

Upload_max_file_size  900000000M
max_file_upload      9000000M

Make sure these two configuration is Upload_max_file_size  always grater then max_file_upload

Restart the server

After this issue will resolve.

Thanks
Vinod K Maurya